# WAMP MySQL will not start now after having unsolved password issues

Tags: mysql, wamp

### Prologue

First I want to mention that the original issue was password related. I kept getting wrong password error in both phpmyadmin and mysql console. I did not change the password to be clear.
**Attempted solutions:**

1. Restarting services
2. Rebooting PC
3. Tried possible default passwords: root, password, 'blank', your_password
4. Inserted `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';` into the first line of file "my.ini", which actually came from here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

**New issue**

After attempt number 4, the server now sefuses to run, wampmysql64 is stuck on starting in windows services. Rolling back the changes did not solve it.
**Attempted solutions(again)**

1. Restarting services
2. Rebooting PC
3. Turning off firewall
4. Port 3306 is not being used by any other service or process.
5. Made sure 'skip-networking' was commented in my.ini
6. Deleting auto.cnf, and ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1

**All failed.** Attempts 5 and 6 came from here https://superuser.com/questions/321744/wamp-mysql-service-will-not-start

**MySQL files**

[my.ini](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a3wz7cd8cmojt82/my.ini?dl=0)
[mysql.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qo9awohwx4pxbp9/mysql.log?dl=0)
**UPDATE**

- inside wampmysql64 properties in services
- general tab
- startup type was set to disabled
- changing it back to manual gave error "service marked for deletion"

**After a reboot**

- wampmysql64 service is gone
- reinstalling it through the wamp menu>mysql>service administration
- It runs now!

**Password Anomaly remains.**
**UPDATE 2**

Password was successfully reset with this code into mysql console, I had to run the server with `skip-grant-tables` uncommented(byremoving the ';') from the my.ini file.

```
UPDATE mysql.user
SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('MyNewPass'), password_expired = 'N'
WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**Reboot, Restart all servives, bingo, connected and password is working. Wait what?......Databases are gone.**

Comment: Good lord, sweet way to draft a question. Just a suggestion, add the files text to your question, as if in future, if you delete the files from your dropbox or you move them to some other folder, the question won't be useful to future visitors.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thank you, yes I did have my doubts on the log posting, the my.ini file is rather long, I didnt know how to share it without cloggin up so much space.

Comment: The usual reason for suddenly and  unexplainably not having the same root password is that you installed something that came with its own MYSQL Server instance, that starts itself automatically at boot time. This other instance of course either has a password on `root` or a differenct password on `root` Did you install something that may fit this bill??

Comment: @RiggsFolly I believe I do, MySQL Workbench has an instance of another server, that was installed months ago, it is not currently running, it never is infact. I just ran it out of curiosity, and that one works.

Comment: I was going to ask if you had installed WorkBench. Thats the usual suspect

Comment: Normally Workbench's version of MYSQL installs a service called `MYSQL` and it is set to Auto start at boot. Because WAMPServers MYSQL with a service called `wampmysqld` or `wampmysqld64` only starts when you launch WAMPServer it never get to start as the other one is already started and listening on port 3306

Comment: So the problem now is what MYSQL contains your databses.

Comment: Yes, in services, mysql57 is the workbench instance, not running, wampmysqld64 is the one with my databases, it is stuck on starting. Mysql Notifier shows their status as "stopped" and "startpending" respectively.